# Add php code inside xml that make xml run in one domain

Tags: php, xml, vbulletin

I have a vbulletin template that I want to install it in just one domain.this is the php code that checks domain:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'domainname.com') {
     //run
}else{
     echo "this template runs in domainname.com "
}
?>
```

how can I use it inside the xml file for preventing installation template in another domain?

Comment: You want to use PHP in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You can add the code in the XML file, however it's not executed when importing. If there is no VBulletin built-in function - and I'd bet there isn't - you have no chance.

Best guess may be to add some JavaScript Code (if it's an template for html) which alerts the users if it's stolen, but it would be easy to get rid of. Note that this is bad practice however, maybe you want to reuse this a few years later; you'd have to fight your very own copy protection first.

Best you just keep your template private if you don't want anyone other using it or do a side note for your coworkers if it's a company website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nevertheless there is no way to encode vbulletin template ?

Comment: @user2781069 no. It's like an image: You may add a copy right, you may search google images regulary to check wether someone else uploaded it, but you may not use it without exposing it fully to the user. You could embedded an image from your site to find if others using it or some JS as noted above, but that's about all you can do.